# Android Using OnTouchListener in Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, ontouchlistener

So, I'm developing an app where user will be able to interact with image, I need to use OnTouchListener, but I don't know how to do it properly. Whenever I click on image - nothing happens. In the end I'm trying to get circle that will appear when user touches the image and that'll move with the finger. Here's my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/boxes.jpg");

        String fileString = file.getPath();


        takenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileString);
        mutableBitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        takenPhoto.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);

    }

    private static class DrawView extends View {



        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }


         public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {


                int action = event.getAction(); 

                drawPos.x = event.getX();
                drawPos.y = event.getY();

                switch (action) { 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    drawing = true;
                    this.invalidate();
                    break; 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    drawing = false;
                    this.invalidate();
                    break; 

                default: 
                    break; 
                }



             return true;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

             super.onDraw(canvas);

             if (drawing) {
                 canvas.drawCircle(zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y, 100, mPaint);
             }
         }





    }


}
```

Comment: If you replace the setOnTouchListener in setOnClickListener, can you able to interact with image?

Comment: No. I can't use OnClickListener since it does not have MotionEvent that I require

Comment: Where are you using DrawView? In the above code you set a touch listener to the image view which swallows all touch events and does nothing.

Comment: Removing OnTouchListener did not help. Nothing happens with the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to use a custom ImageView that will handle both the image and the draw:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DrawingImageView extends ImageView {

    private PointF point;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawingImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DrawingImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DrawingImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                point = new PointF(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                point.set(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                point = null;
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (point != null) {
            canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 100, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your xml file:

```
    <your.package.DrawingImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And in your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //...
    view = (DrawingImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    //...
    view.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
}
```

That's all

Comment: I'm not sure if it's simpler. Can you tell me what you meant by "you should add a DrawView above the ImageView"?

Comment: Really, this method is simpler. It avoids aving to handle multiple views. It's better to have only one view, that handles the image, the touch events, and the drawing stuf. Seriously, you just have to import these two snippets of code. The previous method would requires you to add a view above the ImageView, and make sure it has the same size, etc...

Comment: Works like charm.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the last `onTouch` method from your Activity and remove `setOnTouchListener`.
Since the activity captures touch event, the view will never get access to it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/boxes.jpg");
        String fileString = file.getPath();
        takenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileString);
        mutableBitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        takenPhoto.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);
    }

    private static class DrawView extends View {

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

         public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction(); 
                drawPos.x = event.getX();
                drawPos.y = event.getY();

                switch (action) { 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    drawing = true;
                    this.invalidate();
                    break; 
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:   
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    drawing = false;
                    this.invalidate();
                    break; 

                default: 
                    break; 
                }
             return true;
         }

         @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
             super.onDraw(canvas);
             if (drawing) {
                 canvas.drawCircle(zoomPos.x, zoomPos.y, 100, mPaint);
             }
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Removing OnTouchListener did not help. Nothing happens with the image

Comment: Indeed, this will happen in the DrawView. You should create one, and add it to the view root

Comment: I don't quite understand. What should I create in DrawView. setOnTouchListener or image?

Comment: No, you should add a DrawView above the ImageView. It will therefore capture touch event and draw the circle below your finger

Comment: How? I'm sorry that I ask, perhaps, such trivial question, but how? Frankly, it's my first time using different class to draw canvas.